# Converting number to a padded string

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, enable-if, numeric-limits

I am trying to convert numeric types to fixed length string representations with leading '0's (used in a GUI that can only deal with strings - and lexicographic sorting of numbers is really awkward).

Instead of creating the string on the spot where it is required, I figure it should be possible to make a nice template for others to use that also works with different arithmetic types.

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
std::string arithmeticToMaxLengthString(const T& value)
{
  std::string number, result;
  number = std::to_string( value );
  result = lpad( '0', std::numeric_limits<decltype(value)>::digits10 + 1, number );
  return result;
}

std::string lpad( char filler, std::string::size_type length, const std::string& input)
{
  std::string result;
  if( input.length() < length )
  {
     result.append( lenght - input.lenght(), filler ).append( input );
     return result;
  }
  return input;
}
```

So far so good.
It compiles and I can use it.
BUT:

When I tried using it, I got a surprise.
Calling this function with an int32_t which is

```
typedef int int32_t;
```

that has a value of 100 the result is the string "100", length 3.

I am pretty certain that no other template with such a bad name exists in the codebase (I have search through all of it, and all linked libraries), but I can not seem to understand what is wrong with the code I have produced.
To verify the code to be correct I have just copy-pasted it to the place it is called, which now basically looks like this:

```
myDataClass{
  int32_t     quantity;
  std::string numberAsString;
}

void setNumberString( myDataClass data )
{
   std::string result    = arithmeticToMaxLengthString( data.quantity );
   std::string reference = lpad( '0', std::numeric_limits<decltype(value)>::digits10 + 1, std::to_string(data.quantity) );
   std::cout << "quantity<" << data.quantity << "> numericLimits<" << std::numeric_limits<decltype(value)>::digits10 + 1 << ">" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "result  template: length<" << result.lenght()    << "> content<" << result    << ">" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "result reference: length<" << reference.lenght() << "> content<" << reference << ">" << std::endl;
}
```

Now to my understanding the template "arithmeticToMaxLengthString" is called with int32_t as the type of the argument, which is a normal int, where "numeric_limits::digits10 + 1" gives me 10.
But when this funtion is now called with a quantity of say 100 the results differ.

```
quantity<100> numericLimits<10>
result  template: length<3> content<100>
result reference: length<10> content<0000000100>
```

Am I missing something about templates, enable_if or numeric_limits?
In what way does the template differ (aside from the obvious enable_if) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem happens because you are passing a reference to `arithmeticToMaxLengthString` function. For reasons listed in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51926270/5517378), `std::numeric_limits` does not work with references.

Therefore, I am suggesting you to use template type `T` for getting the numerical limit instead of using `decltype(value)`:

```cpp
result = lpad('0', std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10 + 1, number);
```

Not only does it solve the problem, it looks much more elegant too.

Comment: !?!? The hell? Thanks - will try this out as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really the answer to your question, but the suggestion of how to implement the same functionality using `STL`.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T, unsigned N = 5>
std::string to_string_with_leading_0(T element) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setw(N) << std::setfill('0') << element;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
So far we are still avoiding stringstream mostly because of performance reasons.
We had tried changing it but on the systems the software is deployed in general this gives slightly worse performance with a higher memory footprint. Because of that we also still have many printf-like functions too.
but if all else fails i will have to resort to that.

NutCracker has now also explained why it didn't work as expected.